# How to use numba parallel?

Tags: python, performance, parallel-processing, numba, low-latency

I am trying to parallelize or optimize the following example code with numba. However, I still do not get the logic behind this.

The parallel diagnostics indicate that parallel structure is already optimal.

```
from numba import njit
@njit(parallel=True)
def SwVer(ResSwc,SwNew,Ia,Ja,Ka):
    for k in (Ia):
        for j in (Ja):
            for i in (Ka):
                if(SwNew[i,j,k]<ResSwc):
                    SwNew[i,j,k]=ResSwc
                if(SwNew[i,j,k]>(1-ResSwc)):
                    SwNew[i,j,k]=(1-ResSwc)
    
    return SwNew

import numpy as np
Imax=100
Jmax=100
Kmax=5

Ia=np.arange(0,Imax,1)
Ja=np.arange(0,Jmax,1)
Ka=np.arange(0,Kmax,1)

SwNew=np.random.random((Imax,Jmax,Kmax))
SwNew=SwVer(0.25,SwNew,Ia,Ja,Ka)
```

How can I truly parallelize this function?
Does loop unrolling improve execution time?
Is there any other way to improve my triple loop?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Q** : *"Does loop unrolling improve execution time?"*

Loop unrolling is fine for avoiding the looping overheads, yet there are more problems for larger and multi-level looping, given the flattened "length" of the `A[N,N,N]` soon grows for **`N`** above `~ 1E3, 1E4, 1E5` way above just a few **`GB`**.

> **Q** : *"Is there any other way to improve my triple loop?"*

Avoid passing redundant "parameters". It is expensive. The more the larger these get.
***`Ia, Ja, Ka`*** - re-represent the natural domain indices of the *`A[i,j,k]`*, which are already present inside the *`A`*-instance, aren't they? Passing and receiving large, redundant parameters is a luxury we often prefer to avoid.

```
@njit(parallel=True)
def SwVer( ResSwc,   SwNew,           Ia, Ja, Ka ):
    #                     [: : :]     ||  ||  ||
    for                        k in (         Ka ):
        for                  j   in (     Ja ):
            for            i     in ( Ia ):
                if ( SwNew[i,j,k] <        ResSwc ):
                     SwNew[i,j,k]  =       ResSwc
                if ( SwNew[i,j,k] >  ( 1 - ResSwc ) ):
                     SwNew[i,j,k]  = ( 1 - ResSwc )
    #                SwNew[:,:,:]
    return           SwNew
```

---

### The as-was STATE-0 :

The as-was code was executed in about **`~ 1,824,168 [us] ~ 1.8 [s]`**.

---

### A small STEP-for a man :

In-place modifications are always faster, than having many same-sized intermediate instances to collect final results, which is another high-performance grade code anti-pattern.

Just the removal of the last line **`return SwNew`** yields **`~ 714,977 [us] ~ 0.7 [s]`**

---

### Now
a *small STEP* for a Man,
but
a ***GIANT LEAP for the MANKIND** <sub>( ... The Performance ... )</sub>* :

For a unique performance on trivial *`[i,j,k]`*-mapable transformations may like to try the brave **`numpy`**-vectorised computing.

The whole trick is this short : `np.where( A > T_hi, T_hi, np.where( A < T_lo, T_lo, A ))`

Your function can run anywhere between **`12086 [us]`** and **`97810 [us]`** in **`numpy`**-vectorised mode. The physical RAM, cache, CPU, O/S workloads' details will cause variable effects, yet RAM-sizes matter for a smart-vectorised code, and the **`numpy`** is smart and a lot, the most:
**`A[1000,1000,1000] ~ 8 [GB]`**-RAM-footprints. Yet details matter. A lot.
**`A[ 100, 100, 100] ~ 8 [MB]`**-RAM-footprints. Now it does fit in L3/L2 cache ... that matters...
**`A[  10,  10,  10] ~ 8 [kB]`**-RAM-footprints. Now it does fit in L1d-cache ... that matters. A lot...

---

### Let's be Quantitative from the *very* start :

We start here with a 2D-reduced dimensionality, because of the RAM.

```
>>> from zmq import Stopwatch;  aClk = Stopwatch()     # a [us]-resolution clock
>>> pass;    import gc;               gc.disable()     #   ...  elementary
>>> pass;    import numpy as np
#_______________________________________________________________________________
>>> N = int( 1E3 ); aClk.start(); A = np.random.random( ( N, N, N ) ); aClk.stop()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "mtrand.pyx", line 861, in mtrand.RandomState.random_sample
  File "mtrand.pyx", line 167, in mtrand.cont0_array
MemoryError
```

Nevertheless, the vectorised code trick remains the same in principle for 1D- ... nD-tensor processing :

```
#_______________________________________________________________________________
#       [us]
#_______________________________________________________________________________
>>> N = int( 1E4 ); aClk.start(); A = np.random.random( ( N, N ) ); aClk.stop()
17801992
>>> N = int( 1E3 ); aClk.start(); A = np.random.random( ( N, N ) ); aClk.stop()
  184895
>>> N = int( 1E2 ); aClk.start(); A = np.random.random( ( N, N ) ); aClk.stop()
    1585
>>> N = int( 1E1 ); aClk.start(); A = np.random.random( ( N, N ) ); aClk.stop()
      44
>>> N = int( 1E2 ); aClk.start(); A = np.random.random( ( N, N ) ); aClk.stop()
     465
>>> N = int( 1E3 ); aClk.start(); A = np.random.random( ( N, N ) ); aClk.stop()
   48651
>>> N = int( 1E4 ); aClk.start(); A = np.random.random( ( N, N ) ); aClk.stop()
 4954694
>>> N = int( 1E4 ); aClk.start(); A = np.random.random( ( N, N ) ); aClk.stop()
25549190
#_______________________________________________________________________________
#       [us] SEE THE GROWING COSTS FOR ram-ALLOCATIONS & STORAGE OF RANDOM num-s
#_______________________________________________________________________________


>>> N = int( 1E3 ); aClk.start(); A = np.random.random( ( N, N ) ); aClk.stop()
  471956
   50067
   49184
   42891
   48897
   52639
   45464
   48828
#_______________________________________________________________________________
#       [us] SEE THE 1st, resp. WAY-LOWER COSTS FOR 1st, resp. OTHER ram-ACCESS
#_______________________________________________________________________________


>>> T_lo = 0.25; T_hi = 1 - T_lo; aClk.start(); A = np.where( A > T_hi, T_hi, np.where( A < T_lo, T_lo, A ) ); aClk.stop()
   71044
   12086
   16277
   28192
#_______________________________________________________________________________
#       [us] SEE ALSO THE "noise" IN THE LATENCY-COSTS IN 2nd+ RE-RUN-s
#_______________________________________________________________________________

>>> N = int( 1E3 );               aClk.start(); A = np.random.random( ( N, N ) );                              aClk.stop()
   45759
>>> T_lo = 0.25; T_hi = 1 - T_lo; aClk.start(); A = np.where( A > T_hi, T_hi, np.where( A < T_lo, T_lo, A ) ); aClk.stop()
   38362    
   46640
   37927

>>> N = int( 1E4 );               aClk.start(); A = np.random.random( ( N, N ) );                              aClk.stop()
 4885472
>>> T_lo = 0.25; T_hi = 1 - T_lo; aClk.start(); A = np.where( A > T_hi, T_hi, np.where( A < T_lo, T_lo, A ) ); aClk.stop()
35747022
#_______________________________________________________________________________
#       [us] SEE THE SHIFT IN LATENCY-COSTS AS ram-i/o COSTS DOMINATE > 1 [GB]
#_______________________________________________________________________________


>>> N = int( 1E3 );               aClk.start(); A = np.random.random( ( N, N ) );                              aClk.stop()
 2307509
   50446
   49464
   43006
   50958
   54800
   43418
   57091
   52135
   46451

>>> T_lo = 0.25; T_hi = 1 - T_lo; aClk.start(); A = np.where( A > T_hi, T_hi, np.where( A < T_lo, T_lo, A ) ); aClk.stop()
   97810
   20117
   14480
   22696
   31172
   14846
#_______________________________________________________________________________
#       [us] SEE THE "noise" FOR 2nd+ RE-RUN-s
#_______________________________________________________________________________

>>> N = int( 1E3 );               aClk.start(); A = np.random.random( ( N, N ) );                              aClk.stop()
   47437
>>> T_lo = 0.25; T_hi = 1 - T_lo; aClk.start(); A = np.where( A > T_hi, T_hi, np.where( A < T_lo, T_lo, A ) ); aClk.stop()
   39298
   19422
#_______________________________________________________________________________
#       [us] SEE THE "noise" FOR 2nd+ RE-RUN
#_______________________________________________________________________________

>>> N = int( 1E3 ); aClk.start();               A = np.random.random( ( N, N ) );                              aClk.stop()
   44814
>>> T_lo = 0.25; T_hi = 1 - T_lo; aClk.start(); A = np.where( A > T_hi, T_hi, np.where( A < T_lo, T_lo, A ) ); aClk.stop()
   42565

>>> N = int( 1E3 ); aClk.start();               A = np.random.random( ( N, N ) );                              aClk.stop()
   43120
>>> T_lo = 0.25; T_hi = 1 - T_lo; aClk.start(); A = np.where( A > T_hi, T_hi, np.where( A < T_lo, T_lo, A ) ); aClk.stop()
   38039

>>> N = int( 1E3 ); aClk.start();               A = np.random.random( ( N, N ) );                              aClk.stop()
   45296
>>> T_lo = 0.25; T_hi = 1 - T_lo; aClk.start(); A = np.where( A > T_hi, T_hi, np.where( A < T_lo, T_lo, A ) ); aClk.stop()
   41898
#_______________________________________________________________________________
#       [us] SEE THE "noise" FOR block-RE-randomised-RE-RUN-s
#_______________________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: Thanks for the multiple answers and the comparative table at the end. It is much more clear to me now. I started reviewing this parallelization problem in my code and I tried to apply it to a much larger function but I came across the following question. Is it possible to evaluate each element of a matrix with something similar and improve performance? ie `A(i,j,k)=F(B(i,j,k))` Where f(x) is a linear interpolation.

Comment: Sure @Eduardo. The best read about all this is the `numpy`-vectorisation documentation & `numpy`-broadcasting restrictions. Be also warned, that the cache-re-use efficiency matters, so FORTRAN column-wise memory layouts may help for large-scale data processing, if striving to shave-off the last few microseconds in the performance hunt.

Answer (score 1):

You have at least two performance critical issues in the code.

- Numpy arrays are per default C-ordered (last dimension changes fastest), therefor the inner loop should iterate on the last axis.
- You are using index arrays to iterate on the data. This has a significant overhead (memory and performance) and is completely unnecessary.

**Three lops**

Apart from very simple problems it is usually necessary to use `nb.parfor` explicitly. Also note that the parallel version is slower on quite tiny problems with runtimes in range of µs.

```
@njit(parallel=False) #True for parallel
def SwVer(ResSwc,SwNew):
    for i in range(SwNew.shape[0]):
        for j in range(SwNew.shape[1]):
            for k in range(SwNew.shape[2]):
                if(SwNew[i,j,k]<ResSwc):
                    SwNew[i,j,k]=ResSwc
                if(SwNew[i,j,k]>(1-ResSwc)):
                    SwNew[i,j,k]=(1-ResSwc)
    return SwNe
```

**One loop**

```
#only works on contigous arrays, otherwise reshape will fail
@njit(parallel=False)
def SwVer_unrolled(ResSwc,SwNew):
    shape_orig=SwNew.shape
    SwNew_flat=SwNew.reshape(-1) #create a 1d-view
    for i in nb.prange(SwNew_flat.shape[0]):
        if(SwNew_flat[i]<ResSwc):
            SwNew_flat[i]=ResSwc
        if(SwNew_flat[i]>(1-ResSwc)):
            SwNew_flat[i]=(1-ResSwc)
    return SwNew_flat.reshape(shape_orig)
```

**Numpy vectorized version**

```
def SwVer_np(ResSwc,SwNew):
    SwNew[SwNew<ResSwc]    =ResSwc
    SwNew[SwNew>(1-ResSwc)]=(1-ResSwc)
    return SwNew
```

**Timings**

```
#very small array
Imax=100
Jmax=100
Kmax=5

Ia=np.arange(0,Imax,1)
Ja=np.arange(0,Jmax,1)
Ka=np.arange(0,Kmax,1)

#your version
%timeit SwVer_orig(0.25,SwNew,Ia,Ja,Ka)
#181 µs ± 1.92 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit SwVer(0.25,SwNew)
#parallel=False
#44.6 µs ± 213 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
#parallel=True
#104 µs ± 5.61 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
%timeit SwVer_unrolled(0.25,SwNew)
#parallel=False
#11.4 µs ± 96.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
#parallel=True
#116 µs ± 4.45 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
%timeit SwVer_np(0.25,SwNew)
#30.1 µs ± 568 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

#bigger arrays -> parallelization beneficial
Imax=1000
Jmax=1000
Kmax=5
SwNew=np.random.random((Imax,Jmax,Kmax))

#your version
%timeit SwVer_orig(0.25,SwNew,Ia,Ja,Ka)
#17.7 ms ± 165 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit SwVer(0.25,SwNew)
#parallel=False
#4.73 ms ± 96.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
#parallel=True
#1.3 ms ± 63.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
%timeit SwVer_unrolled(0.25,SwNew)
#parallel=False
#2.03 ms ± 18.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
#parallel=True
#1.17 ms ± 30.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
%timeit SwVer_np(0.25,SwNew)
#7.9 ms ± 100 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

**Conclusion**

If this part isn't extremely performance critical I would prefer the Numpy vectorized version, because of its simplicity. You can outperform it, but I don't think that it is worth the effort here.

Comment: Hello @max9111, thank you very much for the answer and the timing comparison. This part of code is a small portion of a bigger time loop with a similar structure. I tried to apply the one loop option but it did not work since some of my operations are position dependent. 
`Tra[21],Tra[23],Tra[22],Tra[51],Tra[50]=Tw(Nfgx[i,j,k],bw[i+1,j,k],Kw[i+1,j,k],NKx[i+1,j,k],vw[i+1,j,k],Bw[i+1,j,k],Dbw[i+1,j,k],Dvw[i+1,j,k],DKw[i+1,j,k],DPc[i+1,j,k])`
I am still trying to figure this part out. Just a quick question. When you say _last dimension changes fastest_ can you explain that again? 
Best,

Comment: @Eduardo You can check the array order eg. with `SwNew.flags`. It can be C_CONTIGUOUS , F_CONTIGUOUS or arbitrary. By default it is C_CONTIGUOUS. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order This concept stays the same in higher dimensional arrays.